# Changing frame extremely slow in Sequencer

Tags: video-sequence-editor

i have a simple png sequence and an audio. 2000 frames 24fps. very simple setup. no other effects. it used to work fine but all of a sudden when i click into any frame in the sequencer it is extremely slow to respond. i have set cache to 8GB, i have 32GB memory. this is only 1 minute animation. do i need to click something to "load all frames" into memory so it instantly can change frame on demand because it is virtually impossible to do a frames scrub.

[image]

Comment: have you tried with another version of Blender? Also are you using proxy (which will lighten the calculation)?

Comment: yes i tried it on 2.93, 3.0, and 3.1 all take 3-4 seconds to click change frame. how do i use proxy? i read that it is deprecated?

Comment: well, it's weird if it used work fine, but actually PNGs are quite heavy and 2000 of them starts to add up, so dunno... Proxy is the way to go for a responsive VSE when editing, but they only work with videos, not image sequences. Personally I probably would render those sequences as lossless videos, have Blender proxy them at 25%, then edit that